# InvalidArgumentError when serving model on CPU, no issues on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to import a model I trained on a GPU ec2 instance to an ec2 instance that **doesn't** have a GPU for inference, and I'm having some issues when calling the `model.predict()` function.

I've tried setting the device to only using the available CPU on the instance and that didn't help, and I'm pretty sure this is the problem as I've recreated my pipenv environment on a different ec2 instance with a GPU, ran the same code I have for inference, and had no issues.

Here's my code for the model inference:

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# A preprocessed pandas dataframe I read in
f_listing_data = pd.read_csv("f_listing_data.csv")

def df_to_array(df):
    """Converts a pandas dataframe to a list of numpy arrays"""
    array_list = []
    for col in df.columns:
        array_list.append(df[col].values)
    return array_list

def r2(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true))) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )

def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))

# loading in my pretrained model
inf_model = keras.models.load_model('keras_instant_price_no_upload.h5', custom_objects={'rmse':rmse, 'r2':r2})

# dropping target label and getting predictions 
preds = inf_model.predict(df_to_array(f_listing_data.drop("price", axis=1)))
```

Here's what my pipenv Pipfile looks like for my environment setup (I'm using packages downloaded from a private Pypi server):

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "http://$PYPI_USERNAME:${PYPI_PASSWORD}@{SERVER_IP}:{SERVER_PORT}/"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
scikit-learn = "*"
xgboost = "*"
pandas = "*"
numpy = "*"
tensorflow = "*"
ipython = "*"
keras = "*"
loftydatafetcher = "*"  # a custom package for downloading/uploading data

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

My Pipenv graph:

```
ipython==7.7.0
  - backcall [required: Any, installed: 0.1.0]
  - decorator [required: Any, installed: 4.4.0]
  - jedi [required: >=0.10, installed: 0.15.1]
    - parso [required: >=0.5.0, installed: 0.5.1]
  - pexpect [required: Any, installed: 4.7.0]
    - ptyprocess [required: >=0.5, installed: 0.6.0]
  - pickleshare [required: Any, installed: 0.7.5]
  - prompt-toolkit [required: >=2.0.0,<2.1.0, installed: 2.0.9]
    - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.12.0]
    - wcwidth [required: Any, installed: 0.1.7]
  - pygments [required: Any, installed: 2.4.2]
  - setuptools [required: >=18.5, installed: 41.2.0]
  - traitlets [required: >=4.2, installed: 4.3.2]
    - decorator [required: Any, installed: 4.4.0]
    - ipython-genutils [required: Any, installed: 0.2.0]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.12.0]
Keras==2.2.5
  - h5py [required: Any, installed: 2.9.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.7, installed: 1.17.0]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.12.0]
  - keras-applications [required: >=1.0.8, installed: 1.0.8]
    - h5py [required: Any, installed: 2.9.0]
      - numpy [required: >=1.7, installed: 1.17.0]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.12.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.9.1, installed: 1.17.0]
  - keras-preprocessing [required: >=1.1.0, installed: 1.1.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.9.1, installed: 1.17.0]
    - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.12.0]
  - numpy [required: >=1.9.1, installed: 1.17.0]
  - pyyaml [required: Any, installed: 5.1.2]
  - scipy [required: >=0.14, installed: 1.3.1]
    - numpy [required: >=1.13.3, installed: 1.17.0]
  - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.12.0]
loftydatafetcher==0.2.3
  - boto3 [required: Any, installed: 1.9.216]
    - botocore [required: >=1.12.216,<1.13.0, installed: 1.12.216]
      - docutils [required: >=0.10,<0.16, installed: 0.15.2]
      - jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<1.0.0, installed: 0.9.4]
      - python-dateutil [required: >=2.1,<3.0.0, installed: 2.8.0]
        - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.12.0]
      - urllib3 [required: >=1.20,<1.26, installed: 1.25.3]
    - jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<1.0.0, installed: 0.9.4]
    - s3transfer [required: >=0.2.0,<0.3.0, installed: 0.2.1]
      - botocore [required: >=1.12.36,<2.0.0, installed: 1.12.216]
        - docutils [required: >=0.10,<0.16, installed: 0.15.2]
        - jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<1.0.0, installed: 0.9.4]
        - python-dateutil [required: >=2.1,<3.0.0, installed: 2.8.0]
          - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.12.0]
        - urllib3 [required: >=1.20,<1.26, installed: 1.25.3]
  - mysql-connector [required: Any, installed: 2.2.9]
  - pandas [required: Any, installed: 0.25.1]
    - numpy [required: >=1.13.3, installed: 1.17.0]
    - python-dateutil [required: >=2.6.1, installed: 2.8.0]
      - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.12.0]
    - pytz [required: >=2017.2, installed: 2019.2]
  - sqlalchemy [required: Any, installed: 1.3.7]
scikit-learn==0.21.3
  - joblib [required: >=0.11, installed: 0.13.2]
  - numpy [required: >=1.11.0, installed: 1.17.0]
  - scipy [required: >=0.17.0, installed: 1.3.1]
    - numpy [required: >=1.13.3, installed: 1.17.0]
tensorflow==1.14.0
  - absl-py [required: >=0.7.0, installed: 0.7.1]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.12.0]
  - astor [required: >=0.6.0, installed: 0.8.0]
  - gast [required: >=0.2.0, installed: 0.2.2]
  - google-pasta [required: >=0.1.6, installed: 0.1.7]
  - grpcio [required: >=1.8.6, installed: 1.23.0]
    - six [required: >=1.5.2, installed: 1.12.0]
  - keras-applications [required: >=1.0.6, installed: 1.0.8]
    - h5py [required: Any, installed: 2.9.0]
      - numpy [required: >=1.7, installed: 1.17.0]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.12.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.9.1, installed: 1.17.0]
  - keras-preprocessing [required: >=1.0.5, installed: 1.1.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.9.1, installed: 1.17.0]
    - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.12.0]
  - numpy [required: >=1.14.5,<2.0, installed: 1.17.0]
  - protobuf [required: >=3.6.1, installed: 3.9.1]
    - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 41.2.0]
    - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.12.0]
  - six [required: >=1.10.0, installed: 1.12.0]
  - tensorboard [required: >=1.14.0,<1.15.0, installed: 1.14.0]
    - absl-py [required: >=0.4, installed: 0.7.1]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.12.0]
    - grpcio [required: >=1.6.3, installed: 1.23.0]
      - six [required: >=1.5.2, installed: 1.12.0]
    - markdown [required: >=2.6.8, installed: 3.1.1]
      - setuptools [required: >=36, installed: 41.2.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.12.0, installed: 1.17.0]
    - protobuf [required: >=3.6.0, installed: 3.9.1]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 41.2.0]
      - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.12.0]
    - setuptools [required: >=41.0.0, installed: 41.2.0]
    - six [required: >=1.10.0, installed: 1.12.0]
    - werkzeug [required: >=0.11.15, installed: 0.15.5]
    - wheel [required: >=0.26, installed: 0.33.6]
  - tensorflow-estimator [required: >=1.14.0rc0,<1.15.0rc0, installed: 1.14.0]
  - termcolor [required: >=1.1.0, installed: 1.1.0]
  - wheel [required: >=0.26, installed: 0.33.6]
  - wrapt [required: >=1.11.1, installed: 1.11.2]
xgboost==0.90
  - numpy [required: Any, installed: 1.17.0]
  - scipy [required: Any, installed: 1.3.1]
    - numpy [required: >=1.13.3, installed: 1.17.0]
```

I expect the results of the predictions to be an array 1 float value per row in the data I pass into the `model.predict()` function. These are the results I get on my GPU instance (I should mention that I'm running this code from a Jupyter Notebook):

```
>>> preds = inf_model.predict(df_to_array(f_listing_data.drop("price", axis=1)))
>>> preds[:5], len(preds)

(array([[0.18931788],
        [0.08384943],
        [0.48033524],
        [0.19470096],
        [0.16680539]], dtype=float32), 340)
```

This the error stack trace I get when running this same line of code on my CPU instance (running in ipython):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6559eecde46a> in <module>
     27 
     28 # dropping target label and getting predictions
---> 29 preds = inf_model.predict(df_to_array(f_listing_data.drop("price", axis=1)))

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/xgb_listing_pred-eH2Cah04/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1399                                             verbose=verbose,
   1400                                             steps=steps,
-> 1401                                             callbacks=callbacks)
   1402 
   1403     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/xgb_listing_pred-eH2Cah04/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in predict_loop(model, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks)
    330             batch_logs = {'batch': batch_index, 'size': len(batch_ids)}
    331             callbacks._call_batch_hook('predict', 'begin', batch_index, batch_logs)
--> 332             batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    333             batch_outs = to_list(batch_outs)
    334             if batch_index == 0:

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/xgb_listing_pred-eH2Cah04/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2977                     return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2978 
-> 2979             return self._call(inputs)
   2980         else:
   2981             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/xgb_listing_pred-eH2Cah04/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2935             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2936         else:
-> 2937             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2938         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2939 

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/xgb_listing_pred-eH2Cah04/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0] = 1490 is not in [0, 38)
         [[{{node embedding_22/embedding_lookup}}]]
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: Unsubscribe to the Apache helicopter and try again.